# non static, private variable value is somehow shared/overwritten in a multi thread run

Tags: java, multithreading

See if you guys could solve this. It is driving me insane.

I have 2 instances of a Class which has private instance `File` variables (NOT static, NOT volatile)

```
private File tmpF;
```

each instances were then executed in different threads in the same pool.

instance 1 and 2 both create a temp file and assigned it to its `File` variable (NOT static).  I called

```
tmpF = File.createTempFile("myTempFile" + unique_Id)
```

right before temp file creation, I debugged using IntelliJ IDEA and verified that each thread has different `unique_Id`.

Here is what is driving me insane.  When the latter threads created a temp file and assigned it to its own `tmpF` variable, the earlier thread `tmpF` variable's value changed to the latter thread's tmpF value.  How is this possible when `tmpF` is NOT static ???

When I tried changing the variable into a local method variable. The problem disappears... so it is definitely something to do with the fact that is a class field. Adding synchronized doesn't work either interestingly.

Comment: If `tmpF` is a non-static member of your class, the most likely explanation is that your two instances of the class are, in fact, two references to *the same* instance. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem sounds like you are sharing mutable data between threads, which ought to be avoided in concurrent environments, as per Brian Goetz's book, [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601). You have a few different options, depending on your restrictions.

1. If your class instances are really meant to be local to a single thread, try refactor your field so that it is final (i.e. `private final File tmpF;`), ensuring that it is instantiated exactly once. The file could be injected from a factory class.
2. If your class has a single instance and is shared between threads and you really need to have each thread use it's own file, try using Java's [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) class.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank You ent, i will take a look at the mentioned resources.

Comment: Cool. Let me know if you have any follow up questions.